# Header redirects not working as expected

Tags: php, redirect, header

I have the following function which retrives the currently logged in users' username and finds out their access level from the database (either 'requested','user', or 'admin')

```
function fetchAccess()
    {
    global $con;
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $q = "SELECT access FROM users WHERE username = '$username'  LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($q, $con);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $access = $row['access'];

    if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
        {

        if($access == 'user')
            {
            return 1; // Returns 1 if access level is user
            }
        elseif($access == 'admin')
            {
            return 2; // Returns 2 if access level is admin
            }
        elseif($access == 'requested')
            {
            return 3; // Returns 3 if access level is requested
            }
        }
    }
```

When I am checking whether the user is an admin using the follow code, this works correctly.

```
/* Redirects user if access level does not equal admin */
    $result = fetchAccess();
    if($result != 2)
        {
        header("location:index.php");
        }
```

However when I check to see whether the access is 'requested' - this following is NOT working correctly.

```
<?php

/* Redirects user if access level does is 'requested' */
    $result = fetchAccess();
    if($result == 3)
        {
        header("location:redirect.php");
        }

?>
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: how does it not work correctly? Doesn't redirect at all? You should start off by putting `exit;` after the redirect, to stop it from processing the rest of the script

Comment: just a small point - header() just sends headers. if it's a redirect, you should exit after the header() line, as it's possible you may accidentally send secure info that you were unaware you were sending.

Comment: You should turn error reporting on.  I bet headers are already being sent, so it won't let you redirect.

Comment: One would assume the 3rd bit of code is not running because in the second bit of code you are redirecting 1 and 3

Comment: also, is the last "elseif" really necessary? if there are only 3 levels, then do an if/elseif for 1 and 2, and then just return 3

Comment: yes, that's correct. the different headers may overwrite one another unless you exit the script.

Comment: Have you tried echo $result; just to see what your result shows?

Comment: Hey all, thanks for the comments. I've now added the exit(); and rewrote the code to just return 3 as per Kae Verens advice and its now working :)

Comment: Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
function fetchAccess()
    {
    global $con;
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $q = "SELECT access FROM users WHERE username = '$username'  LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($q, $con);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
global $access
    $access = $row['access'];
}
```

then:

```
global $access
if($access != admin){
   header("location:redirect.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that $result actually equal to 3? it may very well be that in the first instance $result == "" which is != 2 so it is not working at all.  Try debugging it by including a header like:

```
<?php

    $result = fetchAccess();
    header("X-my-result: [$result]");
    if ( $result == 3 ) {
         header("Location: redirect.php");
    } 

?>
```

and see what you get back for value of $result in the headers.

Answer (score 0):

do an echo statement to see what is return in the $result variable.  btw, i'm not sure if your logic in your first redirect statement is to encompass both 'user' and 'requested', but those users will be redirected to index.php